# how can i fix the error in epubcheck 3.01.jar

Tags: java, epub

Is there any one knows how to fix the error below. Before I have epubcheck-1.2.jar and it perfectly worked in my program and now i try to incorporate this new epubcheck-3.0.1.jar. I encounter this error. **I am not a java developer**, hope someone can help me here.. I need to upgrade my program because the for epub 2 and epub 3, or there is any one knows an offline validator.

Epubcheck Version 3.0.1

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thaiopensource/validate/SchemaReaderFactory
    at com.adobe.epubcheck.ocf.OCFChecker.<clinit>(OCFChecker.java:65)
    at com.adobe.epubcheck.api.EpubCheck.validate(EpubCheck.java:205)
    at com.adobe.epubcheck.tool.Checker.validateFile(Checker.java:172)
    at com.adobe.epubcheck.tool.Checker.run(Checker.java:255)
    at com.adobe.epubcheck.tool.Checker.main(Checker.java:182)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thaiopensource.validate.SchemaReaderFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like You missed at least one dependency

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thaiopensource/jing/20091111

here it is on maven. if you add this to your project anything should be ok.

Comment: Thanks, but i still have question on adding on my project.. my program just used shell arguments like below in calling the epubcheck-3.0.1.jar, see below

Comment: `var str7 = "\"" + Application.StartupPath + @"\epub_Validator\" + Global.EPubJavaValidator + "\"";
                        var str8 = "\"" + str6 + "\"";
                        var str9 = "\"" + str5 + "\"";
                        Interaction.Shell("\"" + Global.SupportPathConv + "\\epubvalidator.exe\" " + str7 + " " + str8 + " " + str9, AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus, true);`

Comment: where Global.EPubJavaValidator is epubcheck-3.0.1.jar

Comment: sorry, i have trouble with understanding what kind of software you using, but if i understand all right, just look for / bin directory, you need to copy jing.jar. what you got from maven, to  / bin of your software. and try to run it again. After all, i get some advice from epubcheck contributors, in archive, that you downloaded from site, also should be 'lib' directory. make sure that you copy all jars from it to your / bin.